# How to provide access to Kubeflow on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I have followed the steps in [Kubernetes Engine for Kubeflow](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started-gke/).

The deployment went fine and all pods/services are up, including the endpoint at `https://<name>.endpoints.<project>.cloud.goog/`, with the correct `<name>` and `<project>` of course.

When I went to the above url, I was redirected to a "Sign in with Google" page. I assumed that OAuth was also configured correctly.

However, after signing in, I was shown an Access Denied page below.

Is there another way to provide access? I thought it was handled by OAuth.

[image: Access Denied]

Comment: I would recommend trying to sign in via incognito window and see if this works. Also please ensure that the oauth credentials are configured properly as shown in this [link](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started-gke/).

Comment: Please make sure to use to sign in to Kubeflow browser using a GCP account with admin privileges for your GCP project as stated in the [tutorial](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started-gke/).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was following "Deploy Kubeflow on GKE using the command line". Your 2nd comment was for "Deploy Kubeflow on GKE using the UI" which I tried and it works. I must have missed a step and I suspect it is related to IAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deployment created by `kfctl.sh` in "Deploy Kubeflow on GKE using the command line" also creates a load balancer resource for the ingress into the cluster and secures it using Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP).

To allow access to the resource for new users, go to:

Google Cloud Console > IAM & Admin > Identity-Aware Proxy

Select the desired resource and click "Add Member".

Fill in the user in the "Access Denied" page and select "Cloud IAP > IAP-Secured Web App User" for role.

Once the policy change is propagated, the user will be able to access the URL successfully.